# Automate transects within polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, geotools, transects

I have a river polygon file and want to make transects parallel to the flow of the river. Transects can be any length, but must be 100 m apart from each other. I need enough transects to "cover" the whole river, assuming a 100 m buffer on either side (200 m wide part of river: 1 transect in center). The transects won't all be parallel with each other since the river is not straight. What is the quickest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Digital Shoreline Analysis System](https://www.usgs.gov/centers/whcmsc/science/digital-shoreline-analysis-system-dsas) to create transects at certain intervals.

The tool requires a baseline and shorelines of different years. You can convert the river polygon to a line and use one side of the line as baseline.

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Pro has [this](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/tool-reference/data-management/generate-transects-along-lines.htm) native tool for creating transects are regular intervals along a line.  Also, [this ArcGIS 10x toolbox](https://github.com/ShuksanGeomatics/Create_Perpendicular_Lines_ArcGIS) tool will create perpendicular lines to a feature class and center points and/or line ends.

You could [create a center line from your polygons](https://hub.arcgis.com/content/bc642731870740aabf48134f90aa6165/about).  Then use the native ArcGIS Pro tools or  for ArcMap you could then [divide the resulting line into 100m segments](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/ways-to-split-a-line-feature.htm) and generate the perpendicular lines on those 100m segments.